# How to set an arrival time in Google Maps desktop that is not on the hour?

Tags: google-maps

When getting directions from Google Maps, you can set an arrival or departure time. On the Android app, you can set any time you like, but on the desktop webapp, you are limited to only "on the hour" options.

[image: Maps arrival time picker only on the hour]

Is there any way to force the site to accept an arrival time of say, 18:30?

Comment: In all the options where I can pick a "depart at", or "arrival time" I am given 15 minute increments.

Answer (score 1):

Time has marched on. Checking some train journeys out of Edinburgh (where OP is shown as based) and elsewhere (UK and abroad) the dropdown has consistently been at half-hourly intervals for me and the granularity 20 minutes (with the forward of backward options) - for both departures and arrivals.